# ¿Cuál es el error? Hallar el porcentaje de pares, impares y ceros

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    int num[100];
    int n_pares=0;
    int n_impares=0;
    int ceros=0;
    int p_pares;
    int p_impares;
    int p_ceros;

cout<<"numero de digitos : ";
cin>>n;

for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    cout<<"numero "<<i<<":"<<endl;
    cin>>num[i];

    if(num[i]==0)
    {
        n_pares=n_pares+1;
    }
    else if(num[i]==1)
    {
        n_impares=n_impares+1;
    }
    else if(num[i]==0)
    {
        ceros=ceros+1;
    }
}

p_pares=((n_pares)/n)*100;
p_impares=((n_impares)/n)*100;
p_ceros=((ceros)/n)*100;    


cout<<"\n";
cout<<"-----------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"porcentaje de pares : "<<p_pares<<endl;
cout<<"porcentaje de impares : "<<p_impares<<endl;
cout<<"porcentaje de ceros : "<<p_ceros<<endl;

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: La pregunta no se me hace lo mejor planteada posible, además de la edición que hizo @Shaz no se porque no se toman el tiempo de plantear su pregunta con un buen titulo y un buen acomodo del código.

Comment: ¿`0` debe contarse como par?

Comment: ¿Esto es C o C++?

Comment: @NaCl asumo que C++, ya que `cout` no existe en C (por lo que `#include <conio.h>` sobra).

Answer (score 4):

Es mejor si el bucle itera desde cero:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

La comprobación puede hacerse con:

```cpp
if(num[i] == 0)
    ceros++;
else
    (num[i] & 1) ? n_impares++ : n_pares++;
```

Una alternativa también puede ser:

```cpp
if(num[i] == 0)
{
    ceros++;
}
else if (num[i] & 1)
{
    n_impares++;
}
else
{
    n_pares++;
}
```

Todo número impar tiene el bit menos significativo activado. Por otra parte, los números pares, siempre tienen su bit menos significativo igual a cero.

Podemos aprovechar esa particularidad si usamos el operador `AND` de bit a bit (`&`), no confundir con el `AND` lógico (`&&`).

```
  xxxx ... xxx0    número par en binario, un ejemplo puede ser el número 20: 0010 0100
&             1
  -------------
              0   =>  Resultado 0, entonces el número es par


  xxxx ... xxx1    número impar en binario, un ejemplo puede ser el número 21: 0010 0101
&             1
  -------------
              1   =>  Resultado 1, entonces el número es impar
```

Luego, para calcular los porcentajes es preferible trabajar con variables numéricas de tipo flotante `float`, pero si se quiere usar enteros, entonces se debe dejar la división para lo último, es decir que debe ser la última operación de la línea de código:

```cpp
p_pares   = 100 * n_pares/n;
p_impares = 100 * n_impares/n;
p_ceros   = 100 * ceros/n;
```

Código completo:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    int num[100];
    int n_pares=0;
    int n_impares=0;
    int ceros=0;
    int p_pares;
    int p_impares;
    int p_ceros;

cout<<"numero de digitos : ";
cin>>n;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout<<"numero "<<i+1<<":"<<endl;
    cin>>num[i];

    if(num[i] == 0)
        ceros++;
    else
        (num[i] & 1) ? n_impares++ : n_pares++;        
}

p_pares=100*n_pares/n;
p_impares=100*n_impares/n;
p_ceros=100*ceros/n;    

cout<<"\n";
cout<<"-----------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"porcentaje de pares : "<<p_pares<<endl;
cout<<"porcentaje de impares : "<<p_impares<<endl;
cout<<"porcentaje de ceros : "<<p_ceros<<endl;

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: No es absolutamente necesario tener 3 contadores. Por ejemplo, se puede calcular `n_impares = n - n_pares - ceros`.

Answer (score 2):

Para saber si un número es par bastaría con verificar `si el residuo de la división de un número entre 2 es igual a 0` , tal residuo se obtiene con el operador mod (%)

En este caso el inconveniente estaría en un ciclo `for` al momento de comparar la entrada para saber si es par o impar, quedaría así haciendo las modificaciones y los arreglos inician en la posición 0

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout<<"numero "<<i<<":"<<endl;
    cin>>num[i];

        if(num[i]==0) n_ceros+=1; 
        else  if(num[i] %2==0)n_pares+=1;
}
n_impares = n-(n_pares+n_ceros);
```

Comment: No es absolutamente necesario tener 3 contadores. Por ejemplo, se puede calcular `n_impares = n - n_pares - ceros`.

Comment: @Mariano tu cálculo asume que `0` no es par ni impar.

Comment: @Mariano se a lo que te refieres. Puedes deducir la cantidad de elementos de un conjunto sabiendo la cantidad de elementos de otros dos. Pero eso sólo funciona si los conjuntos son disjuntos.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster acabo de leer bien tu comentario (había interpretado al revés). Sí, estoy asumiendo (viendo el código del autor) que no se considera al `0` como par... Es incorrecto, pero muchas veces lo vi así en estos ejercicios.

Comment: @Mariano de hecho, según el código del autor el único número par del universo es el `0` xD

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Cuál es el error?

Múltiples errores.

1. Los arreglos en C++ se indexan desde `0`.

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    cout<<"numero "<<i<<":"<<endl;
    cin>>num[i];
```

El código anterior recorre el arreglo `num` desde `1` a `n`; ambos incluidos. Si `n` fuese `100` estarías escribiendo fuera del bucle ya que los índices van del `0` al `99`. Si cambias el código a:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout<<"numero "<<i<<":"<<endl;
    cin>>num[i];
```

Recorrerías los índices correctamente (gracias ArtEze). Dado que los arreglos de C++ se indexan desde `0`, el código que recorría el bucle desde `1` dejaba el índice `0` sin tocar.

2. No se sabe si un número es par al compararlo con `0`. Lo único que averiguas es si el número es `0`.

```
if(num[i]==0)
{
    n_pares=n_pares+1;
}
```

3. No se sabe si un número es impar al compararlo con `1`. Lo único que averiguas es si el número es `1`... menos aún encadenando la comprobación tras comprobar si vale `0`:

```
if(num[i]==0)
{
    n_pares=n_pares+1;
}
else if(num[i]==1)
{
    n_impares=n_impares+1;
}
```

4. Nunca contarás números que sean exáctamente `0` porque ya los has contado como pares, la rama `if-else if-else if` en que incrementas `ceros` nunca es tomada para valores `0` ya que éstos entran en el primer `if`:

```
if(num[i]==0)
{
    n_pares=n_pares+1;
}
else if(num[i]==1)
{
    n_impares=n_impares+1;
}
else if(num[i]==0)
{
    ceros=ceros+1;
}
```

---

Por ejemplo, para valores `0`, `111` y `222` contarás `0` como par (primer if), `111` como nada (no entra en ningún `if`) y `222`como nada (no entra en ningún `if`).

#### Propuesta.

> Hallar el porcentaje de pares, impares y ceros

Usa [`<algorithm>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count):

```
auto begin = std::begin(num);
auto end = std::end(num);
const float total = n;

float p_pares   = std::count_if(begin, end, [](int n){ return !(n % 2); }) / total;
float p_impares = std::count_if(begin, end, [](int n){ return (n % 2); }) / total;
float p_ceros   = std::count_if(begin, end, [](int n){ return !n; }) / total;

std::cout << "\n-----------------------\n";
std::cout << "porcentaje de pares : "   << 100.f * p_pares   << '\n';
std::cout << "porcentaje de impares : " << 100.f * p_impares << '\n';
std::cout << "porcentaje de ceros : "   << 100.f * p_ceros   << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

Para no cambiar tu código, trabajaré con el que ya tienes:

Una cosa MUY importante es en las operaciones que utilizas para hallar los porcentajes.

```
p_pares=((n_pares)/n)*100;
p_impares=((n_impares)/n)*100;
p_ceros=((ceros)/n)*100;
```

Son correctas, pero aquí se encuentra un gran problema:

> Cuando declaras las variables n_pares, n_impares y ceros. Ya que las estás declarando como enteros, int, pero cuando realizas las operaciones de división, no se guarda la división correcta, ya que estás usando con enteros, y no números reales.
>   Por lo que para tener un resultado de porcentaje correcto es necesario declarar las variables n_pares, n_impares y ceros como double, no como int.

Además, hay errores en la comprobación de pares:

En este "if", compruebas si el número es igual a 0, lo cual no implica que sea par o impar, simplemente si es cero.
Para comprobar con if si el número es par podemos comprobar el resto del número dividido entre dos:

> if (num[i] % 2 == 0)  ---> Comprueba si el numero en el array es PAR

```
    if(num[i]==0)
    {
        n_pares=n_pares+1;
    }
```

Lo mismo ocurre con el impar, no hace falta poner la condición, si no es par, es impar. Por lo que un else y añadir 1 al contador de impares sería suficiente.

```
    else if(num[i]==1)
    {
        n_impares=n_impares+1;
    }
```

Y aquí, si quieres contar cero como par y además como cero, el else sobra. De lo contrario ningún cero aparecerá ya que se quedaría en el if de pares.

```
    else if(num[i]==0)
    {
        ceros=ceros+1;
    }
}
```

**Solución sugerida para el for**

```
//Recuerda declarar las variables n_pares, n_impares 
//y ceros como double
double n_pares = 0;
double n_impares = 0;
double ceros = 0;

/* Codigo */

for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    cout<<"numero "<<i<<":"<<endl;
    cin>>num[i];

    // Si quieres contar el cero de forma independiente a los pares
    //añade un else al final de este if
    if(num[i]==0)
    {
        ceros=ceros+1;
    }

    if(num[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        n_pares=n_pares+1;
    }
    else
    {
        n_impares=n_impares+1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para verificar si es par o no deberias hacer `if(num[i] % 2 == 0)` y si no es par es impar.